# Error - JSON getting into infinite loop

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to display JSON data, for that i am using fasterxml jackson. I am able display JSON but the JSON is getting to infinite loop and in log file i am getting error as

> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/EAD].[spring]]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw
>   exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException$Reference from
>   [Module "deployment.EAD.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Here is my controller method.

```
@RequestMapping("/viewDashboard")
@ResponseBody
public ModelMap test(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @RequestParam String name) {

    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    List<Instances> instances = viewDashboardServiceImpl.viewDashboard();
    return modelMap.addAllAttributes(instances);

}
```

Actually my Instance.java is having relation with Application.java and Environment.java

Following are my model.java

Here is my instance.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "instanceId")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String instanceName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "appId")
private Applications applications;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "enviId")
private Environments environments;

@Column(name = "version")
private String version;
```

Here is my Application.java

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "appId")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "ownerName")
private String ownerName;

@Column(name = "version")
private String version;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "applications", targetEntity = Instances.class)
private Set<Instances> instances;
```

Here is my Environment.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "enviId")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "ownerName")
private String ownerName;

@Column(name = "version")
private String version;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "environments", targetEntity = Instances.class)
private Set<Instances> instances;
```

Here is my JSON

```
{"instances":{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc","instances":[{"id":2,"instanceName":"SAP BW DEV1","applications":
```

As above JSON keeps going on with repeated data. 
I am having following dependency in maven also.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And i have added following snippet in servlet.xml also.

```
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You have a cyclycal dependency. You are gonna have to annotate some of your collections with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: As mentioned above, you've cyclic dependencies and data is available at each level which is causing this infinite.

Comment: Thank you all, yes there is cyclic dependency and it is resolved by @JsonIgnore

Comment: @dambros after adding annotation (@JsonIgnore) for variable private Set<Instances> instances in both application and evironment.java, looping go resolved and new problem came, In json i am getting only the record. Actually i am having 3 records in a table, all three are coming i a list but while converting into JSON i am getting only the last record.

Comment: {"instances":{"id":3,"instanceName":"JAVA","applications":{"id":1,"name":"SAP","ownerName":"Mou","version":"3.2.1abc"},"environments":{"id":1,"name":"DEV1","ownerName":"Mou","version":"1.23.asd"},"version":"2.3as"}}

Comment: But in table i am having three records

Comment: JsonIgnore should have nothing to do with this. Are you sure the list you are serializing has 3 object inside?

Comment: yes, i am checking list before returning in controller.    
ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();

List<Instances> instances = viewDashboardServiceImpl.viewDashboard();

  log.info(instances.size());
  return modelMap.addAllAttributes(instances);

In log it showing size as 3 but in JSON i am getting only one record that too last record.

Comment: take a look: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

Comment: Even after removing @JsonIgnore annotation, it is taking the last record and keeps on looping. So the JSON mapping is happening only for the last record.