# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using twilio SMS

Tags: java, twilio, jackson-databind, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Java web in Netbeans 8.2 RC

I try to send an SMS message using Twillio client:

```java
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
Message message = Message.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(getContact()),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+phonenumber"),
                "Sample message"
).create();
```

The message is successfully delivered.

But the code does not continue after *.create()*.
Following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
```

#### What I tried

I do not have a `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. I only have `web.xml`

I have already imported the libraries: **twilio-8.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

How can I solve this issue?

The libraries I have:

[image: Libraries]

Comment: Try to add pro guard rules for twilio.  -keep class com.twilio.** { *; }

Comment: where should i add it

Comment: Which libraries did you use that (re)produce the error: `twilio-8.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` or the older `8.8.0` from your screenshot❔ Please also __post the complete error-output with stack-trace__ 

Comment: It was solved using twilio-7.14.0 jar
Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Twillio SDK, exactly the `create()` method, seems to depend on Jackson (FasterXML converter library), particularly its module for handling *Java8 DateTime* (JSR-310). This is obvious when a call of `create()` results in a `NoSuchMethod...` for a missing method of class `JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase`.

If you would have included the complete error output such as the **stack-trace** of this exception, then we could have easily seen that.

### Analysis

ℹ️ A `NoSuchMethod` runtime-error is usually not caused by `import` statements or `web.xml`. It usually correlates with mismatching dependency-versions.

See the *Twilio Java SDK* v 8.9.0 (jar) as [shown in Maven's web-UI](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/8.9.0/jar) (same as v 8.8.0) includes `pom.xml` with following *dependency*:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>?
```

and under the *properties* the required **version**:

```xml
 <jackson.version>2.12.1</jackson.version>
```

#### Check dependency versions

Make sure that this **jar or package is included** within the Twillio jar or at least on your classpath.
⚠️ Also the **versions must match** (e.g. jackson-core v1 is often depending on jackson-datatype v1). A newer or older version may either change the method (currently not found) i.e. the call or the method-declaration.

#### Did the method change in Jackson versions?

In previous version (2.11) I also found the method `findFormatOverrides` with expected signature (parameters and return types) in class [`JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/2.11/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java).
It was called inside the JsonDeserializer for a Java date-time property. Here when the deserializer is created in context, the parent-class' method is called:

```java
@Override public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {

    JsonFormat.Value format = findFormatOverrides(ctxt, property, handledType());
```

### Solving suggestions

See [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror). A comment to that question fits yours:

> In **Netbeans**: Right click on project in Projects tab, use **"Clean and Build".** Solved it for me.

This [article on NoSuchMethod](https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/) is very helpful for this issue.

#### Use Gradle or Maven

You should consider to use a dependency-management and build-automation tool like *Maven* or *Gradle*:

- Twilio: Java Helper Library, [Using with a build automation tool](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java#using-with-a-build-automation-tool)
- suggested in similar question: [json - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931426/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-jsonmappingexcept)

Comment: @user15520720 It's nothing to do with `web.xml`. It's about dependencies (classes l in your __classpath__. Is there any __other Jackson jar__ that may interfere (version-wise, e.g. an older version where this method did not exist)❔

Comment: i think the issue is with i being using ```import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;```

Comment: @user15520720 No, I doubt. This issue is with __conflicting dependencies that clash at runtime__: While Jackson-core (ObjectMapper) tries to deserialize the Twilio API response from JSON to Java-object, deeply in stacktrace, it calls this method and fails with `NoSuchMethodError`. See my updated answer, how I would solve: use Gradle or Maven. ️